# I can't connect to MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I keep getting a error "MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.". I've been looking at other questions that get a similar error butI did not find a solution after trying multiple different things.

in package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

in index.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

/* CONFIGURATIONS */
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/assets")));

/* FILE STORAGE */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/assets");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });


/* MONGOOSE SETUP */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));

  
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

in .env

```
MONGO_URL = 'the connection string'
PORT = 3001
```

Comment: What do you see if you use `dotenv.config({ debug: true });`?

Comment: Does your mongo url have an `@` symbol in the password. I had an issue like that previously.

Comment: failed to load \desktop\project\.env ENOENT: no such file or directory @rickhg12hs

Comment: I do not  but i do have a special symbol in my password @Innovin

Comment: If `dotenv` can't find `.env`, none of those variables will be set as expected.

Comment: do you have an idea of how solve the issue of dotenv not finding .env? @rickhg12hs

Comment: `dotenv` is looking for it at `\desktop\project\.env`.  I suppose it's not there - should it be?  Alternatively, you could [tell `dotenv` where `.env` is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-path).